# Scrolling in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am developing a Web interface in GWT and when I deploy it, the scrolls do not work. My layout is a RootLayoutPanel which contains a VerticalPanel. This VerticalPanel contains at the same time a TabLayoutPanel and an HorizontalPanel.

```
RootLayoutPanel rootLayout = RootLayoutPanel.get();
rootLayout.setStyleName("RootLayoutPanel");
rootLayout.add(mainVerticalPanel);
RootPanel.get("main").add(rootLayout);
```

Moreover, with regard to the CSS file, it is as follows:

```
.RootPanel {
    background: url(img/fondoAplicacion.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.RootLayoutPanel {
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Could someone help me at enabling the scrolls?

Comment: Why don't you use a Scrollpannel (http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html )

Comment: Use ScrollPanel will fix your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of panels in GWT.

Most widgets (FlowPanel, HTMLPanel) take their height from their internal components: the more widgets you add to them, the taller these panels get.

The other type of panels implements RequiresResize interface. These panels take their size from their parents. This group includes LayoutPanel, VerticalPanel, ScrollPanel, etc.

In your example, when you add a VerticalPanel to the RootLayoutPanel, this VerticalPanel will have exactly the same height as the RootLayoutPanel no matter what is inside the VerticalPanel. Therefore, it will never "overflow" the RootLayoutPanel.

You need to decide which panel you want to be able to "overflow" and scroll as a result. The most logical approach in your case seems to be adding `ScrollPanel`s inside the tabs of a TabLayoutPanel. Each ScrollPanel will contain a single FlowPanel or HTMLPanel - this is where you add all the content. As the contents of these panels grows, it will overflow the respective ScrollPanel, and scroll bars will appear. A user will be able to scroll inside a tab, while the rest of the page will remain in place.